# getDownloadURL() return's undefined result for variable

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, firebase-storage

i'm wanting to use the "url" (of the getDownloadURL) out of her,
likely, in a variable like this.url. But everything this.url returns is a undefined result.
(I've already made all connections to firebase and import's, etc)
Anyone knows if exist an way to make that? 
Thanks in advance.

[example image of the app running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBUNm.png)

```
  var storage = firebase.storage();
  var storageRef = storage.ref();
  const spaceRef = storageRef.child(`Profis/${this.EMAIL}.png`);
  spaceRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){this.url = url})



console.log("teste: " + this.url);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The download URL is loaded from the Firebase servers asynchronously when you call `getDownloadURL`. Since this may take some time, the code *after* that call immediately continues. Then when the download URL comes back from the server, Firebase calls the code that you specify in the `then` callback.

It's easiest to see this by placing a few log statements in the code:

```
var storage = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
const spaceRef = storageRef.child(`Profis/${this.EMAIL}.png`);
console.log("Before calling getDownloadURL()");
spaceRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
  console.log("Got download URL");
});
console.log("After calling getDownloadURL()");
```

When you run this code, the output is:

> Before calling getDownloadURL()
>
> After calling getDownloadURL()
>
> Got download URL

This is probably not what you expected. But it *does* explain why `testUrl` is undefined when you print it: the value didn't come back from the server yet.

For this reason, all code that requires the download URL needs to be *inside* then `then()` callback (or called from inside it). So:

```
var storage = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
const spaceRef = storageRef.child(`Profis/${this.EMAIL}.png`);
spaceRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
  this.url = url
  console.log("teste: " + this.url);
});
```

This is by the way an extremely common source of confusion for developers new to calling asynchronous Web APIs. Since so many APIs function this way though, I recommend spending some time studying it now, so that you are confused about it less frequently going forward. Some sources:

- [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)
- [javascript assigning value to variable from callback return (timing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25697907/javascript-assigning-value-to-variable-from-callback-return-timing)